# In Swift, I'd like the last 3 sections have only labels in their rows (and NOT text fields)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

In my Swift project I have a table controller view with a table view inside. The table view is divided into 4 section and every section has 4 rows. Currently, each row is formed by a label beside a text field.
My purpose is that only rows in the first section has label beside text field. On the contrary, I want the last 3 sections have only labels in their rows (and NOT text fields).
Please, help me.

That's the code I wrote to manage with this problem but it's not working:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("index ", indexPath.section);

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell") as! TextInputTableViewCell
        cell.configure("", placeholder: "name")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You can have custom TableViewCells for each type.

Comment: http://shrikar.com/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/

Comment: @Federica - put another default cell in else condition .Hope it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are using the same cell for all the rows. You need to define two different rows. You can do this by setting prototype cells to more than one row (two in your case).

Each cell must have its own reuse identifier and it must be unique within that table view.

Then in your `tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` you can ask:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstSectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    //
} else {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("otherSectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    //
}
```

Also note that in Swift you do not need to use parenthesis in if-statement (nor for, while, etc). So I suggest you remove them as they are pointless.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cell in `if(indexPath.section == 0)` block doesn't actually have scope outside that block so any properties set there won't get returned there. If you just want to remove the textField, but keep the label, You can just set the `textField.hidden = true`. Here is how I would go about it.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextInputTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        cell.textField.hidden = false //Assumes TextInputTableViewCell's textField property is called "textField"
        cell.configure("", placeholder: "name")

    } else {
        cell.textField.hidden = true //Not in first section we will hide textField
    }

    return cell
}
```

Doing it this way you can use the same cell class for every cell in your tableView, but just hide what you want based on its section.